# Need some help with errors, culmination of a File System Project

Tags: c++, buffer

class BufferFile{
public:
        BufferFile(IOBuffer &);
        int Open(char *);
        int Create(char *);
        int Close();
        int Rewind();
        int Read(int recaddr = -1);
        int Write(int recaddr = -1);
        int Append();
        IOBuffer & GetBuffer();
    protected:
        IOBuffer & Buffer;
        std::fstream File;
        int HeaderSize;
        int ReadHeader();
        int WriteHeader();
    };

```
BufferFile::BufferFile(IOBuffer & from):Buffer(from){}    

int BufferFile::Read(int recaddr){  
    if(recaddr==1) return Buffer.Write(File);  
    else return Buffer.DWrite(File, recaddr);  
}  

int BufferFile::Append(){  
    File.seekp(0,std::ios::end);  
    return Buffer.Write(File);  
}  

IOBuffer & BufferFile::GetBuffer(){  
    return Buffer;  
}  

int BufferFile::ReadHeader(){  
    return Buffer.ReadHeader(File);  
}  

int BufferFile::WriteHeader(){  
    return Buffer.WriteHeader(File);  
}
```

I am getting several errors form the IOBuffer field, saying that it was not declared in the function scopes or "expected `)' before â€˜&â€™ token" on the constructor.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I believe it isn't closed because of improper formatting. You should ask for a specific doubt rather than posting your entire source code. Also tag it as a homework problem, if it is so.

Comment: Thank you for the details surrounding your problem, but I don't see a question anywhere. What is your question?

Comment: StackOverflow is a website targeted at **professional software developers**.  If you are not sure about what StackOverflow is or how to behave here, please review the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  Your question was closed because it is low quality and unanswerable in any reasonable manner.  If you wish to get good answers, you **must** ask good questions.  Low quality questions like this one are not accepted here.  I would **strongly** suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/1228) for hints on how to ask better questions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, the quality of my questions may have been questionable but it was indeed answerable 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092879/need-some-help-with-errors-culmination-of-a-file-system-project?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several of the errors mention that `class IOBuffer has no member named "pack"`. The message is absolutely correct, it doesn't; if you look at the header, it has a method named `Pack`, with a capital `P`. C++ is case-sensitive!

The errors about "redefinition" are happening because your include files don't have [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to prevent them from being included multiple times -- you need to fix that.

That leaves only a few errors remaining; when you've got everything down to those last few, come back and talk to us again. This time, no images! No links! Just paste the actual text of the error message, and the few lines of code where the errors occur, and somebody will be able to help you.