# Function and Class errors

Tags: c++, buffer

```
class BufferFile{  
public:  
        BufferFile(IOBuffer &);  
        int Open(char *);  
        int Create(char *);  
        int Close();  
        int Rewind();  
        int Read(int recaddr = -1);  
        int Write(int recaddr = -1);  
        int Append();  
        IOBuffer & GetBuffer();  
    protected:  
        IOBuffer & Buffer;  
        std::fstream File;  
        int HeaderSize;  
        int ReadHeader();  
        int WriteHeader();  
    };    

    BufferFile::BufferFile(IOBuffer & from):Buffer(from){}    

    int BufferFile::Read(int recaddr){  
        if(recaddr==1) return Buffer.Write(File);  
        else return Buffer.DWrite(File, recaddr);  
    }  

    int BufferFile::Append(){  
        File.seekp(0,std::ios::end);  
        return Buffer.Write(File);  
    }  

    IOBuffer & BufferFile::GetBuffer(){  
        return Buffer;  
    }  

    int BufferFile::ReadHeader(){  
        return Buffer.ReadHeader(File);  
    }  

    int BufferFile::WriteHeader(){  
        return Buffer.WriteHeader(File);  
    }
```

I am getting several errors form the IOBuffer field, saying that it was not declared in the function scopes or "expected `)' before â€˜&â€™ token" on the constructor, what is causing these?

Here are all the files involved in this project:
[Person.h!](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21303207/Appendix%20F/Person.h)
 [Buffile.cpp](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21303207/Appendix%20F/Buffile.cpp)
[BuffFile.h](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21303207/Appendix%20F/Buffile.h)
[Delim.cpp](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21303207/Appendix%20F/Delim.cpp)
[Delim.h](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21303207/Appendix%20F/Delim.h)
[Fixfld.cpp](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21303207/Appendix%20F/Fixfld.cpp)
[Fixfld.h](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21303207/Appendix%20F/Fixfld.h)
[FixLen.cpp](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21303207/Appendix%20F/FixLen.cpp)
[FixLen.h](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21303207/Appendix%20F/FixLen.h)
[Iobuffer.cpp](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21303207/Appendix%20F/Iobuffer.cpp)
[Iobuffer.h](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21303207/Appendix%20F/Iobuffer.h)
[Length.cpp](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21303207/Appendix%20F/Length.cpp)
[Length.h](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21303207/Appendix%20F/Length.h)
[Varlen.cpp](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21303207/Appendix%20F/Varlen.cpp)
[Varlen.h](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21303207/Appendix%20F/Varlen.h)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need some help with errors, culmination of a File System Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092879/need-some-help-with-errors-culmination-of-a-file-system-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is this (from Buffile.h):

```
#ifndef IOBUFFER
#define IOBUFFER
#include "Iobuffer.h"
#endif
```

... that logic breaks the similar/redundant logic that you have in Iobuffer.h:

```
#ifndef IOBUFFER
#define IOBUFFER
class IOBuffer{
[...]
#endif
```

The problem is that the declaration of "class IOBuffer" in Iobuffer.h is never parsed, because the compiler value IOBUFFER was already defined inside Buffile.h, and thus the #ifndef IOBUFFER at the top of Iobuffer.h is not activated.

The right way to do it is to modify Buffile.h to include only the #include "Iobuffer.h" line, and leave it up to the contents of Iobuffer.h to do the #ifndef and #define stuff.

Comment: I was a little confused by your wording but understood, it worked like a charm thanks.